# R: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: r, rstudio, rcurl

Server SSL Protocols: TLS 1.1, TLS 1.2 are enabled in the server

Works with REDCapR library which is using the same handshake protocol. I've verified the request headers with the fiddler tool. This proves that the server is accepting sslv3 alert handshakes successfully. I'm not sure why RCurl is failing for the same protocol.

Let me know if you need any more information. Thanks in advance!

Curl - Version 3.2,
RCurl - Version 1.95-4.11,
httr - Version 1.3.1,
openssl - Version 1.1